# Opening datepicker dialog on click of a programmatically created editext?

Tags: java, android

I've found numerous tutorials on how to accomplish this when you can grab the textview from the xml but nothing on how to implement such a function when you have multiple edit texts created programmatically that all need the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the `EditText`, you would add a click listener the same way you would to any other view. You may also need to disable the focusable attribute to prevent clicks from activating the keyboard:

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Open dialog here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all EditText's, simply create one OnClickListener, call setOnClickListener on every EditText and pass the OnClickListener Object.

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //open dialog here;
        }
    };
editText1.setOnClickListener(listener);
editText2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

You should maybe store the EditText's in an array, so that you can just loop through all of them.